# Is there a payment method for Sage and worldpay where you arent taken off site?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I was looking at the extensions and most of them seem to take you offsite to then be redirected back. Is there anyway that these methods can be used without being taken away from the checkout?

I know it is kind of a broad question but my client is thinking of going down the route of processing and keeping payment details on our servers and I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ebizmarts Sage Pay](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-europe-free-sagepay-official-extension.html) Free solution is great for this, it gives you direct form integration. The  user is never taken away from your website, except for 3D-SECURE password entry, which pops up in a jQuery inline frame.

Theres no way to do it via Worldpay, as they don't give the full API access for doing so (they only allow redirection). Which is why we ended up using Sagepay

Please note: You will be required to be [PCI DSS Compliant](http://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/15268) if you use fully embedded forms on your site.

Answer (score 2):

with the module I use comes the business interface (XML). You have to be PCI compliant but the processing takes place on the on site.

I can recommend this plugin very much. Here is the link: I hope this helps anybody.

http://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/magento-worldpay-zahlungs-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

No these kind of 3rd party Payment service providers have there contracts and checks done on their platform here-fore they need to process it on their servers and not yours this would give Credit Card owners a security risk

Comment: Sorry I don't mean that the server would handle it (this is what I want to avoid) I meant like some form of iframe just to keep the customer from being completely redirected from the clients site. 

I believe sagepay can do it but I don't know anything about worldpay which would allow this.